# InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified error clicking on div ng-click element with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select

```
<div ng-click="select('expert')" class="select-exp__item select-exp__item_active" ng-class="{'select-exp__item_active': 'expert'===selected}" style="">
```

I have tried a few things

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[ng-click='select('expert')']").click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('select-exp__item-title').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH("//div[@class='select-exp__item select-exp__item_active']").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH("//div[@class='select-exp__item select-exp__item_active' and contains(@ng-click, 'select('expert')')]").click()
```

...but I get the same error each time:

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Grateful for any guidance, have googled "selenium ng-click" extensively without much luck and still learning Selenium, thank you.

Here's the full HTML:

```
<div class="agmodal__wrapper agmodal onboarding-wrapper ng-scope agmodal__wrapper--visible" ng-controller="OnboardingController as ctrl" ng-class="{'agmodal__wrapper--visible': ctrl.shown}" tabindex="-1" style="">
    <div class="onboarding">
        <div class="onboarding__body">
            <!-- ngIf: ctrl.onboardingService.step === 1 --><section class="select-exp step ng-scope" ng-if="ctrl.onboardingService.step === 1" style="">
    <div class="select-exp__header step__header">
        <div class="select-exp__title step__title">Welcome to AMZScout PRO Extension</div>
        <div class="select-exp__desc step__desc">
            PRO Extension helps you find the perfect product to sell on Amazon
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-exp__body">
        <div class="select-exp__body-title">
            Select your experience level with Amazon</div>
        <div class="select-exp__body-desc">
            We will adjust the amount of pop up tips and certain parameters based on your experience. You will be able
            to
            change this choice later in the Settings.</div>
        <div class="select-exp__items">
            <div ng-click="select('beginner')" class="select-exp__item" ng-class="{'select-exp__item_active': 'beginner'===selected}">
                <div class="select-exp__item-title">Beginner</div>
                <div class="select-exp__item-desc">If you are new to Amazon research, you’ll see vital parameters that
                    will help you choose a great
                    product quickly. Great for learning.</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-click="select('expert')" class="select-exp__item select-exp__item_active" ng-class="{'select-exp__item_active': 'expert'===selected}" style="">
                <div class="select-exp__item-title">Expert</div>
                <div class="select-exp__item-desc">As an expert, you’ll see the full data and be able to fine-tune your
                    research.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

...implies that the selector which you have used isn't a valid selector expression.

---

### Analysis

As per your first code trial:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[ng-click='select('expert')']").click()
```

`(` and `)` have a special effect when used within a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors). So the expression stands invalid. You need to escape the characters.

---

### Solution

As the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.select-exp__item.select-exp__item_active[ng-click=\"select('expert')\"]"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='select-exp__item select-exp__item_active' and @ng-click=\"select('expert')\"]"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try located the element with css selector like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.select-exp__item.select-exp__item_active'))).click()
```

You are wrong in using **`WebdriverWait`**, your code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By("value").click()
```

It's should like this pattern:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By, 'value'))).click()
```

[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)