# Python Selenium: How to click on an element that contains text within a div with a class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Very new to Selenium and Python (any form of coding in general). Trying to automate a bot to book a gym slot as they are booking up before I can even get a chance.

I'm trying to get selenium to click on the evening slot. The whole box is selectable
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHdLf.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYxyk.png)

I tried using this

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class='activity-start-time ng-star-inserted')]//span[contains(text(),'5:00PM')]"))).click()
```

but it fails receiving the following exception: InvalidSelectorException. Unable to locate an element with the xpath expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InvalidSelectorException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464384/7429447) indicates that the [*xpath*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882166/7429447) is a bit off and errorprone. As per the [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYxyk.png) the `<section>` tag is having the classes *`activity-start-time ng-star-inserted`* and the text *`5:00PM`*

---

### Solution

You can use the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@class='activity-start-time ng-star-inserted' and contains(.,'5:00pm')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your locator strategy however it bounces back with an invalid selector exception message.

Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression `//section[@class='activity-start-time ng-star-inserted'] and [contains(.,'5:00PM')] ` because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string `''//section[@class='activity-start-time ng-star-inserted'] and [contains(.,'5:00PM')]' ` is not a valid XPath expression.

I'm at a bit of a loss here and can't seem to figure out why the xpath isn't working

Comment: @AminM There was abug in the code. Corrected now. Please retest.

Comment: I've tried the new code once again but it seems to bounce back with the same Invalid Selector Exception. The Syntax Error ''Failed to execute evaluate on Document'' keeps occurring. My understanding is that the section `//section[@class` is not actually being found by Xpath so it can't search for the text ''5:00PM''. I tried some alternatives such as using `//div[contains(@class='activity-view-container ng star inserted')` to see if it can capture the element above the section that contains 5:00pm but it also gives the same invalidselectorexception

Comment: I managed to get it to work. Not sure what I was doing wrong entering the code or copying and pasting but it now correctly selects it. Thank you for your help!